# Sumproduct with table reference returns #Value! Error

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel table with a communication log organized by date. I'd like to generate a report for communication channel by month using the following sumproduct formula.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Communication Type]=B178)*--(Table1[Month]=A179))`

**NB:** Month is a calculated column base on date using =TEXT([@[Contact Date]],"mmmm")

The formula seems sound since i tested in on a normal range of the same data. I'd like some assistance in understanding how to successfully reference the table data. I've reviewed other questions on stack that tackle similar issues but none of those seem to resolve my issue when I tried to apply them.

Please assist. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the SUMPRODUCT function, you'll need two arguments. In your formula, you try multiplying your ranges inside the SUMPRODUCT formula. Instead of that, use a comma:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Communication Type]=B178), --(Table1[Month]=A179))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I Just resolved the issue. There was a lone incorrect date value which returned a #Value! error in a month cell and as a result forced the Sumproduct formula to return an error.   The original formula actually works now. Asterisk serves an alternative to comma in the this instance and is used as the AND operator inside array formulas.